# How to configure dynamic reply topic in Spring JMS

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-ws

I'm using JmsMessageSender inside WebServiceTemplate for Spring-WS communication over JMS. I have to work on topics, so I used [setPubSubDomain](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/support/destination/JmsDestinationAccessor.html?is-external=true#setPubSubDomain(boolean)) method of JmsMessageSender's superclass, and the messages go correctly on target topic. However, the for handling response, a temporary queue is created, **not topic**. How can I setup spring beans to have temporary topic for the response, not queue?

To add one hint, there is a [setReplyPubSubDomain](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/AbstractMessageListenerContainer.html#setReplyPubSubDomain-boolean-) method of AbstractMessageListenerContainer class, which looks exactly what I need, but I have never used this listener container and I'm not sure how could I wrap it into my beans.

My configuration below:

```java
@Bean
public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate() {
    WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
    webServiceTemplate.setMessageFactory(messageFactory());
    webServiceTemplate.setMessageSender(messageSender());
    webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri("jms:topicname.topicname.topicname?priority=3&deliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT&messageType=TEXT_MESSAGE");
    return webServiceTemplate;
}

@Bean
public JmsMessageSender messageSender() {
    JmsMessageSender messageSender = new JmsMessageSender();
    messageSender.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    messageSender.setPubSubDomain(true);
    return messageSender;
}
```